# HDRi not visible when using Mist pass

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, hdri

I am using Blender 2.83 and want to create a scene with a lot of fog, so I've been using the Mist pass. However, this makes the HDRi invisible. Is this a limitation of the Mist pass or are my settings wrong?

These are my mist pass settings:

[image]

And my compositor looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mist pass effectively fades out your scene the further it is from the camera (ie, the more ‘mist’ that light ray has had to travel through). The HDRI by its very nature is out at an infinite distance and, therefore, is completely obscured by the mist.

Comment: But it can be mixed with the render layer to a lower value in the compositor, so that the HDR shows.

Comment: @susu Quite right. Actually, to allow the HDRI to show through you could add a Maths node to Multiply the 0.0->1.0 range of the Mist by a fractional number (eg 0.8) to limit the amount of mist. Or use a Minimum maths node to limit the maximum mist, depending on the desired results.